# Watermarking in Windowed Grouped Aggregation

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I was reading the[Spark Streaming Programming Guide Documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html) and have a query on processing of data based on event time.  I have attached a screenshot from the documentation link which shows the data is being processed even before the event has occurred. 12:21 event is processed in the window of 12:10 - 12:20.  Is the image right or am I wrong?

[image]

Comment: Is anything wrong in my above query? I am unable to understand how 12:21 event was processed in 12:10 - 12:20 window. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Theres a late event at 12:13 which is also owl. I think that is being shown in the 12:10-12:20 time range on the cut taken at 12:20.

The 12:21 owl event I would expect should show up in the 12:20 - 12:30 or 12:15 - 12:25 time range. However, these are not shown in the graph

Answer (score 0):

When you work with real time data there can be scenarios of late arrival data and computation of this data has to be performed on the earlier window data. In this scenario, the result of earlier window data is stored in memory and then aggregated with the late arrival data. But it can cause higher memory consumption as the historical data is stored in the memory till the missed data is arrived which might lead to memory accumulation. In these scenarios, Spark streaming has feature of **watermarking** which discards the late arrival data when it crosses threshold value.

In some cases, business results might have mismatch because of discarding these values. To avoid these type of issues, instead of applying watermarking feature, custom functionality has to be implemented to check the timestamp of data and then store it in HDFS or any cloud native object storage system to perform batch computations on the data. This implementation leads to complexity.